# How do I copy selected node from one tree view to other tree view using javascript or jquery with html and css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How do I copy selected node from one tree view to other tree view using javascript or jquery with HTML and CSS?.Please, anyone, help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign node you want to variable and then append it where you want:

```
var myNode = $('#myNode');
var whereToPlace = $('#place');
whereToPlace.append(myNode);
```

I made code very simple to be as much descriptive as possible